# What are the arguments for using a route generator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, symfony, url-routing

I inherited a code base that uses FOSJsRouting bundle to provide route generation in javascript, but I'm having a hard time understanding what benefit that offers.

Assuming that you have a route:

```
/**
* @Route("/some/resource/{param}/{otherParam}", name="some_symfony_route_name", options={"expose"=true})
*/
```

Why would you want to build URIs using route names:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('some_symfony_route_name',{param: 1, otherParam: 2}) /*...*/ )
```

rather than using the established API endpoints?

```
$.post('/some/resource/1/2' /*...*/ )
```

Comment: URIs could change internally. Let's say you have an URI which you are using everywhere over your project. Now let's say you decide to change the URI. Do you really want to go through every URI and change it manually?

Comment: How is that more work than manually changing all the route names?

Comment: You don't have to if you are just changing the URIs. For instance you want to change `'/some/resource/1/2'` to `'/some/new/resource/1/2'` you will have to change it everywhere, whereas if you use FOSJSRoutingBundle, you don't have to.

Comment: It seems that if it is an exposed API, the route shouldn't change. If it is not intended for wide consumption, then it should only be used by well written, parameterized javascript modules that live in object literals (ie, one place to change it). Is that a poor assumption?

Comment: Yes the route name shouldn't change. You are correct in assuming that. However I have been using it pretty much everywhere since I work with external JS files sometimes. The bundes gives a pretty sleek way to access all my URIs outside the twig file as well.